# Firebase check if user is following or followed status

Tags: swift, firebase, database-design, datasource

I am building a firebase app where I want to distinguish if the user is a following or followed status on the same table view. For example, the current user has followed another user and received a following user. So I now have two cells on the table view with the same user but different statuses. The current user only wants to delete one of the cells which is the user current user is following but not the user current user followed. So the data is stored as follows:

```
{
  "following" : {
    "OxUahgJPvXY9BPHT6dosmN46mGR2" : {
      "dBYQ4xHEmTfwHlZaFKKhLOA3uuC2" : true
    },
    "dBYQ4xHEmTfwHlZaFKKhLOA3uuC2" : {
      "OxUahgJPvXY9BPHT6dosmN46mGR2" : true,
      "aRRNDyXubTWN3llvTx0216hx1wx1" : true
    }
  },
  "follower" : {
    "OxUahgJPvXY9BPHT6dosmN46mGR2" : {
      "dBYQ4xHEmTfwHlZaFKKhLOA3uuC2" : true
    },
    "aRRNDyXubTWN3llvTx0216hx1wx1" : {
      "dBYQ4xHEmTfwHlZaFKKhLOA3uuC2" : true
    },
    "dBYQ4xHEmTfwHlZaFKKhLOA3uuC2" : {
      "OxUahgJPvXY9BPHT6dosmN46mGR2" : true
    }
  }
}
```

When a user follows current user, it is stored as below. So dBY... has a follower OxU..., and OxU... is following dBY...

```
{
  "following" : {
    "OxUahgJPvXY9BPHT6dosmN46mGR2" : {
      "dBYQ4xHEmTfwHlZaFKKhLOA3uuC2" : true
    },
  "follower" : {
    "dBYQ4xHEmTfwHlZaFKKhLOA3uuC2" : {
      "OxUahgJPvXY9BPHT6dosmN46mGR2" : true
    }
  }
}
```

I'm writing a method where current user checks for the user id that was removed from table cell in the "following" node.

```
extension TableViewController: UITableViewDataSource
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let user = users[indexPath.row]
        if editingStyle == .delete
        {
        // remove following or followed user when swipe to delete
        let ref = Api.REF_FOLLOWING.child(Api.User.currentUserId).child(user.id!)
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:
        {
            snapshot in
            if let _ = snapshot.value as? NSNull
            {
                // user doesn't exist in following node
            } else
            {
                // TWO of the same user ($uid) exists in following node and deletes both cells
                // check if the relationship in "following" node is current user -> $uid or $uid -> current user 
                users.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
        })
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is if current user has the same user as following and follower, I will get true for both cases in my method, so I wouldn't know which cell to delete. I'm new to databases and would appreciate any help!

Comment: need some more clarity on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Are you asking how to organize this in your tableView e.g. this is a tableView or dataSource question or are you asking how to organize this is Firebase?

Comment: Hi @Jay  I'm asking how to organize and talk to my Firebase structure in swift e.g. distinguishing if a user isFollowing by current user or not, so a data source question

Comment: Great! Then we are going to need some help understanding your Firebase structure as it's not clear in the question. Remember - we are looking at this with no knowledge of what you're doing or why, so the structure needs to be clear and include an explanation of the relationship between the nodes. I see a */follower* node with a child node of *uid* and then a child node of that of *"current user $uid": true* but it's not clear why its structured that way. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure.

Comment: @Jay I'm following a tutorial and it's structured this way because it quickly checks if I'm following a user or not, but the problem is when I have a table view that displays the data cell by observing child added user, returning the user according to the node's snapshot key, and after all child is loaded, remove the user cell

Comment: If I try to remove a user cell using the method I've written above, it will remove both cells of the same user

Comment: So it seems like your question is how to work with this data within the tableView, not directly related to Firebase? Also, what does this mean *// TWO of the same user ($uid) exists in following node* You can't have two children in the same node with the same key (uid). Look at this `.child(Api.User.currentUserId)` that's pointing to */following/uid_0*. Then this `.child(user.id!)` so it's pointing to */following/uid_0/uid_1* and there can only be one *uid_1* as a child of *uid_0*. Also, this `user.id!` is dangerous as if it's nil, the app crashes.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the use case but when a user removes a follower, why are you pinging firebase to see if that data exists? You're not doing anything with the data that's returned from firebase so why do that at all? In other words, the tableView should reflect what's in your tableView datasource and that datasource reflects and is in sync with your Firebase data. If something is removed from Firebase, it would therefore not exist in the dataSource, nor the tableView. Take a look at MVC pattern (do an internet search) as it's the backbone of app design.

Comment: Hi Jay, Thanks for the help. I redesigned my data structure.